# Procedure in SQL that accepts dynamic array of inputs

Tags: sql, sql-server

Does SQL Server have the ability to accept a dynamic array of inputs and loop through the values?

For example:

I have multiple products with **productId**. Now, there will be times that I would need to delete some of those products. I can do this now by executing a stored procedure that accepts a **productId** value. My problem is I need to do this one by one.

What I would like to do is to send multiple **productId**'s to the procedure and have the proc loop through those id's.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible in SQL Server 2008 using Table-Valued Parameters, in SQL Server 2005 is work around it by passing a Comma-separated List of Values. You can see all available options and implementations for 2008 [here](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html)
and for 2005 [here](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html).